# Redirection inside a plug in Phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to write a `Plug` which will authenticate users (checking session actually). I have trouble getting redirect route. I think it is because the route generation happens after this plug is activated.

Anyway I got an error like this: `undefined function TestApp.page_path/2`

In regular context `page_path/2` obviously exists and works.

```
defmodule TestApp.Plugs.Authenticate do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(default), do: default

  def call(conn, _)  do
    user = Plug.Conn.get_session(conn, :current_user)
    if not is_nil(user) do
      assign(conn, :user, user)
    else
      conn
      |> Phoenix.Controller.put_flash(:warning, "User is not authenticated.")
      |> Phoenix.Controller.redirect(to: TestApp.page_path(conn, :index))
      |> halt
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: what is page_path ? If it is a function, can you post it

Comment: it's generated inside router with `get "/", PageController, :index`

Comment: Does this work ?     Phoenix.Controller.redirect(to: TestApp.Router.Helpers.page_path(conn, :index, "hello world"))

Comment: yeah, thank you :) can you put this as an anwser so I mark it as accepted? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Router helpers are included in your controllers and view via the `web.ex` file:

```
  def controller do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.Controller
      ...
      import MyApp.Router.Helpers
    end
  end

  def view do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.View, root: "web/templates"
      ...
      import MyApp.Router.Helpers
      ...
    end
  end
```

As you can see, both `controller` and `view` functions import the `MyApp.Router.Helpers` module. This is where your helper (`_path` and `url`) functions are defined.

You can either use the fully qualified name:

```
Phoenix.Controller.redirect(to: TestAppRouter.Helpers.page_path(conn, :index))
```

Or you can import the route helpers and just use `page_path`

```
import MyApp.Router.Helpers
# or
import MyApp.Router.Helpers, only: [page_path: 2]
```

However, if you then use the plug in a pipeline in your router, you will cause a circular dependency and your code will not compile.

Comment: Thank you :) Sandesh Soni already made a comment about this before, but I'll still accept, that was what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Does this work ?
`Phoenix.Controller.redirect(to: TestApp.Router.Helpers.page_path(conn, :index))`

I think Gazler has a valid point. you can either import or full path.

Answer (score 0):

Did you bring the controller helpers in?

```
use TestApp.Web, :controller
```

(I would post that as a comment but don't have the rep)

Comment: I think controller helpers break the controllers when I put the plug inside another controller. Anyway I tried that and it didn't work ;)